# How to find plugin for Flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the source code of a Flutter project that has imported the following packages:

```
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
```

What extensions are these packages related to?

Answer (score 2):

You can find all the packages used by a Flutter project in the `pubspec.yaml` file under the `dependencies` section in the file, the pubspec is found at the root of the Flutter project. There you will see the versions specified as well.

For finding more information on a specific package and what it is used for see [pub.dev](https://pub.dev), the site contains the documentation of the packages. pub.dev is where public Flutter packages normally are hosted.

In the case for flutter_localization:  https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_localization

Comment: thanks @tor-martin-holen, I want to add the **http** extension (from pub.dev) to **vscode** but I can't find it in the extensions list.

Comment: I assume you have followed the install instructions at https://pub.dev/packages/http/install ,`flutter pub add http`. Do note in contrast to the other imports, `import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;` have been imported with a prefix (`http`) so anything in the package must be prefixed with that before any intuitive auto-complete info would show for that package, lets say we want to use the post method in the http-package `http.post(...)`.

Comment: special thanks @tor-martin-holen, my problem is solved by executing commands `flutter pub add [package_name]` in Terminal of vscode.

Answer (score -1):

Okay since its small lib lists let me tell you import **'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';   /// used for language translation**
**import 'package:dio/dio.dart'; for network call**
**import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;   for network call**
**import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart'; /// local storage or local database**
**import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart'; /// more secure flutter storage for storing tokens....**
**import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';  /// just for picking images from device**

Comment: thanks @abu-qudama for reply, but i need to know **exact name of extensions** to adding to my flutter project.